# Route Model Binding and encryption on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

When trying to bind an encrypted company id to a URL I'm coming across an error.
I'm assuming I have every thing I need included and that I can use a custom name like companyEncrypt as it's a custom binding.

Error:

```
FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 48:
Class 'App\Providers\App\Company' not found

use Log;
use Crypt;
use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
```

Code:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    // An a binder for the encrypted company value.
    $router->bind('companyEncypt', function($encryptedValue) {
        try { 
            $decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($encryptedValue);
        } catch (DecryptException $e) {
            Log::info('Dectypt Exception for the company id');
            dd('error');
        }

        return App\Company::where('id', $decrypted)->first();
    });
}
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to your **Company** by either **Company** or **\App\Company**.

Replace

```
return App\Company::where('id', $decrypted)->first();
```

with

```
return Company::where('id', $decrypted)->first();
```

The reason for the error is that when you refer to a class name that is not a fully qualified class name (e.g. **\App\Company**) or the imported class name (e.g. **Company** that you're importing it with **use App\Company**), autoloader looks for the class in the current namespace.

Threfore, if you refer to **App\Company** in **App\Providers** namespace, it tries to load **App\Providers\App\Company** class.

Comment: That works 8|. Thanks a bunch, could you explain the difference? I copied the syntax from the larvel site and they use the App\Company way but it won't work but the Company:: does

Comment: Cool, I though thats why i used \App to say root and not app/providers name space.  Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1):

You already included App\Company on start of your page. Here use App\Company;

Use it like this: `return Company::where('id', $decrypted)->first();`